# How to read a CSV file with multiple delimiter in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a CSV file using spark 1.6

```
s.no|Name$id|designation|salry
1   |abc$12 |xxx        |yyy
```

```scala
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header","true")
  .option("delimiter","|")
  .load("path")
```

if I add delimiter with $ it throwing error one delimiter permitted

Answer (score 2):

You can apply operation once dataframe is created after reading it from source with primary delimiter ( I am referring "|" as primary delimiter for better understanding).

You can do something like below:

sc is the Sparksession

```
val inputDF = sc.read.option("inferSchema", "true")
.option("header", "true")
.option("delimiter", "|")
.csv("/path/to/your/file")

val modifiedDF = inputDF
.withColumn("Name", split(inputDF.col("Name$id"), "\\$")(0))
.withColumn("id", split(inputDF.col("Name$id"), "\\$")(1)).drop("Name$id")

modifiedDF.show(false) will give you the required output
```

Although this might result in data getting wrongly splitted in case there is valid "$" sign in the data which is mistaken as the delimiter. Hence you should use precaution in these scenarios.

There is one library, don't remember its name but it could be univocity which gives you the option of treating multiple symbols as single delimiter like #@ as delimiter. You can google a little in case your use case is for multiple delimiter for each and every column.

Answer (score 0):

might I ask why are you using spark 1.6?
anyways only one delimiter is allowed when reading a csv format.

if its a specific column which you know has one column with values in the format: name$id

maybe try to run some logic on that column and get a df with 2 new columns

setting up the df

```
al df = sc.parallelize(a).toDF("nameid")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [nameid: string]
```

try something like this:

```
df.withColumn("name",substring_index(col("nameid"), "$", 1)).withColumn("id", substring_index(col("nameid"), "$", -1)).show
```

and the output

```
+-------+----+---+
| nameid|name| id|
+-------+----+---+
|name$id|name| id|
+-------+----+---+
```

you can drop the original column after that also

hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Answered for a different question but repeating here. The other solutions posted here have assumed that those particular delimiters occur at a pecific place. However, I am assuming worst that **those delimiters can occur anywhere randomly**.

Giving example for a hypothetical case below using pyspark where delimiters are | and -

**BEWARE**: we are using split and it means that it will split everything, e.g. 2000-12-31 is a value yet it will be split. Therefore we should be very sure that no such case would ever occur in data. As general advice, one should never accept these types of files as there are accidents waiting to happen.

How sample data looks:- in this case we have 2 files in our directory with | and - occurring randomly as delimiters

[image: Sample data pic]

```
# Create RDD. Basically read as simple text file. 
# sc is spark context
rddRead = sc.textFile("/mnt/adls/RI_Validation/ReadMulktipleDelimerFile/Sample1/") 
rddRead.collect() # For debugging
```

[image: How initial rdd looks]

```
import re # Import for usual python regex 

# Create another rdd using simple string opertaions. This will be similar to list of lists.
# Give regex expression to split your string based on anticipated delimiters (this could be dangerous 
# if those delimiter occur as part of value. e.g.: 2021-12-31 is a single value in reality. 
# But this a price we have to pay for not having good data). 
# For each iteration, k represents 1 element which would eventually become 1 row (e.g. A|33-Mech)

rddSplit = rddRead.map(lambda k: re.split("[|-]+", k)) # Anticipated delimiters are | OR - in this case.
rddSplit.collect() # For debugging
```

[image: Split on delimiters]

```
# This block is applicable only if you have headers
lsHeader = rddSplit.first()  # Get First element from rdd as header.
print(lsHeader) # For debugging
print()
# Remove rows representing header. (Note: Have assumed name of all columns in 
# all files are same. If not, then will have to filter by manually specifying 
#all of them which would be a nightmare from pov of good code as well as maintenance)
rddData = rddSplit.filter(lambda x: x != lsHeader) 
rddData.collect() # For debugging
```

[image: Separate Header and Data]

```
# Convert rdd to spark dataframe
# Utilise the header we got in earlier step. Else can give our own headers.
dfSpark = rddData.toDF(lsHeader)
dfSpark.display() # For debugging
```

[image: Final Spark df]